# You’re making money of me. You’re making money from me

Tags: sentence-construction

How would a native speaker say this?

> You’re making money of me
>
> from me
>
> over me
>
> out of me
>
> by me
>
> in favor of me

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on what you want to say.

The following

> You're making money on me.

could be paraphrased as "My efforts or my skills are making a profit for you". There is no sense of "exploitation" here.  You might say something like this when trying to negotiate a salary increase, for example.

If you want to say that another person is (perhaps unfairly) profiting at your expense (for example, they've agreed to pick up an item for you on their way to work, as a favor, but  ask to be reimbursed for 110% of the item's price):

> You're making money off of me.

Answer (score 2):

The expression that you are looking for is:

> You are making money out of me

It suggests that you are exploiting me in one way or another. A pop star might say this to a manager who was charging excessive management fees, for instance.

None of your other suggested phrases is idiomatic although you might also hear **to make money off** something or other.

People would understand **making money from me** but native speakers would prefer **out of me**.

https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72564/make-money-off-of-vs-make-money-out-of

Comment: I have to disagree a little - I think that idiomatically, making money **off**  me is more fluent, and the SE link you post includes [an Ngrams graph showing that in the last 50 years or so "off" has grown and "out of" has declined](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=make+money+out+of%2Cmake+money+off%2Cmake+money+off+of&year_start=1950&year_end=2008&corpus=5&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmake%20money%20out%20of%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20money%20off%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmake%20money%20off%20of%3B%2Cc0).  But certainly either is understandable.

Comment: @stangdon I think that a little disagreement is perfectly in order.